# Remove the first three lines in a text file

Tags: windows-10, script, powershell-5.0

The script generates a list of Musics that will have their LUFS values normalized, however, first I need to eliminate the header from this list. The header contains three lines: The first line is blank, the second line contains the columns Music and LUFS and the third line contains dashes.

I tried to use the command in this link:
[remove-top-line-of-text-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074271/remove-top-line-of-text-file-with-powershell)

List txt file contents:

```
Music                                                                    LUFS
------                                                                   ----
05 - Earth Wind and Fire - September (The Reflex Revision).mp3          -9,6
```

Script:

```
# Receive parameter sent by batch file
Param(
   [decimal]$_vLUF
)
[decimal]$vLUFps = $_vLUF

$files = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\List Music for normalization.txt"
$fileSelect = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\Selection List.txt"

# Read log files and generate the file List Music for normalization.txt 
$logMatches = Select-String -Path "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\*.*" -Pattern '(?<I>^ +I:) +(?<LUFS>.+)|(?<I>^Input Integrated:) +(?<LUFS>.+)' -List | Select-Object -Property FileName -ExpandProperty Matches
    $results = foreach ($log in $logMatches) {
        $pos = $log.Filename.IndexOf("_")
        $leftPart = $log.Filename.Substring(0, $pos)
        $rightPart = $log.Filename.Substring($pos+1)
        $LUFS = $log.Groups | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "LUFS" }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Música = $rightPart
            LUFS = [decimal]$($LUFS.Value -replace " .*")
        }
    }
$vLUFpsLess= ($vLUFps)+ (-0.9)
$vLUFpsGreat= ($vLUFps)+ (-0.5)
$results | Where-Object {($_.LUFS -lt $vLUFpsLess) -or ($_.LUFS -gt $vLUFpsGreat) } | Out-file $files

# Get content from $files to $fileSelect
Set-Content $fileSelect -Value (Get-Content $files)

# Removes blank line, column titles and dashes in $fileSelect
get-content $fileSelect |
  select -Skip 3 |
  set-content "$fileSelect-temp"
  move "$fileSelect-temp" $fileSelect -Force
```

Command in the batch file that sends the parameter to this script:

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"D:\z_Batchs e Scripts\Batchs\Normaliza_LUFS\ArqsNorms_LUFS_pass.ps1\" -_vLUF %_vLUF%'"
```

When I run the command to eliminate the first three lines it says that the file `Selection List.txt-temp` was not found because it doesn't exist. How can this happen if the `Selection List.txt-temp` file was just created?

Error message:

```
move : Unable to find the path 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\Selection List.txt-temp' because he doesn't exist.
No D:\z_Batchs e Scripts\Batchs\Normaliza_LUFS\ArqsNorms_LUFS_pass.ps1:45 character:1
+ move "$fileSelect-temp" $fileSelect -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there another command I can use to delete the first three lines of the text file?

Comment: Looks like it's just spaces in the filename causing the issue. I think you just need to put doublle-quotes round "$files" or something similar.

Comment: It says the error is on Line 45. So this isn’t the complete script and we have no way of knowing what else the script did / does or if it is even this section of code with the error. Have you confirmed the file it is complaining about actually exists?

Comment: @Reg Edit didn't work!

Comment: @Appleoddity As the source report is created without errors, I thought I could just put the part that is giving error, ok? I edited my question and put the script as you requested, thanks.

Comment: Instead of trying to strip out the header from the file, you should prevent the header from being written to the file in the first place. Look into the `Format-Table` or `Export-CSV` commandlets.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? You don't  say what you tried! Also you don't appear to have successfully added the full script as mentioned by someone else trying to help you. The error refers to line 45 but the script is still only 33 lines long. I am voting to close this question as incomplete, requiring debug info.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works:

```
Get-ChildItem $fileSelect | ForEach-Object {
Set-Content (Get-Content $_ | Select-Object -Skip 3) -Path $_
}
```